# how to deal with returning no data in the render method?

Tags: javascript, react-native, return, render

I am calling a const in the `render()` which does not return anything due to not finding data in the database and I don't know how to deal with it so that whenever there is nothing to return, just dont display anything. It displays an error saying: ***"Invariant violation : Component(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null."***

```
render() {
    const food_menu = this.restaurantMenu(1, 'Menu');

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <ScrollView style={style_2.scrollview} scrollEventThrottle={200} directionalLockEnabled=true}>

                {food_menu}

            </ScrollView>
        </View >
    );
}
```

**Edit(return from food_menu):**

```
    $$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
type: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.forward_ref), displayName: "View", render: ƒ}
key: null
ref: null
props: {style: {…}, children: Array(3)}
_owner: FiberNode {tag: 1, key: null, stateNode: selected_restaurant, elementType: ƒ, type: ƒ, …}
_store: {validated: false}
_self: null
_source: {fileName: "C:\vvv\ddd\selected_restaurant.js", lineNumber: 428}
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look into conditional rendering.

More information: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Example:

```js
render() {
    const food_menu = this.restaurantMenu(1, 'Menu');

    return (
        <>
            {food_menu && <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <ScrollView style={style_2.scrollview} scrollEventThrottle={200} directionalLockEnabled=true}>

                    {food_menu}

                </ScrollView>
            </View >}
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `this.restaurantMenu()` returns a Valid React component this should get you going.

```
render() {
    const food_menu = this.restaurantMenu(1, 'Menu');

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <ScrollView style={style_2.scrollview} scrollEventThrottle={200} directionalLockEnabled=true}>

                {food_menu ? food_menu || null}

            </ScrollView>
        </View >
    );
}
```

Obviously there are better ways to go about this problem. One would be to set state inside `restaurantMenu` indicating a successful loading of restaurant menu and then rendering accordingly. In that case, the conditional rendering would change to:

`{menuLoaded ? food_menu : null }`

Comment: What is restaurantMenu returning ?

Comment: It's difficult to say from a limited view. Could you reproduce this problem on codesandbox.